# Getting System.Net.Mail to read from app.settings?

Tags: vb.net

In ASP.NET, I can just put my mailSettings in web.config and then System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient's default constructor will read them.  In a regular VB.NET project, not ASP.NET, I thought I could just put mailSettings in app.config.  However, SmtpClient() doesn't appear to read settings from app.config.  Is there a step I'm missing in order to tell a VB.NET application to read from app.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to work for me:

### App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="mysmtphost" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

### Module1.vb

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        Console.WriteLine(client.Host)
        ' output is "mysmtphost" as expected
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Hmpfh.  I hadn't tried this myself.  I always did it using the method I suggested.  I'll have to try this next time.  +1 - Good answer.

Comment: Thanks.  The above works just fine for me.  After much head scratching, I learned that there's a bug in Azure Worker Roles which cause app.config to be ignored.  That was my problem.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/jnak/archive/2009/08/17/using-app-config-in-the-july-2009-ctp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the Asp.Net runtime has extra code to handle this for you, probably because the designers expect sending emails to be a normal part of a web site's operations (but I probably shouldn't guess about Microsoft's motives.)

You can read the setting yourself and set the smtp host by reading the settings with the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.`

Or, since you're in VB, you can access this more easily by using `My.Settings`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up about My.Settings.  I don't see that anywhere in the VB.NET book I have, which is probably just a port from the author's C# version of the book.  Both are by Troelsen.

Answer (score 0):

The SmtpClient will not read it automagically, but you can do it easily...

for eg, in V2.0 of the framework, you could do this:

String host = (String)ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SmtpHostName"]

and in your app.exe.config file:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="SmtpHostName" value="Smtp.mydomain.com"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think your XML didn't post.  Angle brackets are probably stripped out by StackOverflow unless you take special measures.